# How to start a code from the beginning all the time?

Tags: python

I'm just beginning with programming and cant figure out how to repeat this code. I want it to just start from the beginning all the time and to end the code when an empty string is applied.

The code down below:

```
name = input('Whats your name? \n')
number = int(input('Whats your number? \n'))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to spend some time [reading this excellent free book](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/howtothink/latest/howtothink.pdf) which is specially written for beginners. The [official python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) is a good resource too but requires a bit more programming experience.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to put it inside a loop. A while for example.

```
name = '' # empty strings have a truthiness value of being false,
while not name: # so if the name is empty run the code inside the while loop
  name = raw_input('Name: ')
print('Hello {}'.format(name)
```

https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to put all your code inside a while loop, that will make your code run all over again from the start, here in this code it will run forever, or until you kill it

as for the string checking, you can check the length of the string using `len` function.

You can close the program using `exit()` or you can use `break` to end the infinite loop

```
while True:
    name = input('Whats your name? \n')
    if not len(name):
        break
    number = input('Whats your number? \n')
    if not len(number):
        break
    number = int(number)
```